# DNS Error after the crash of VPN and the file get's over written

Tags: dns, vpn

I was using a proton VPN for some purpose of testing and Due to some reason I needed to shut down my laptop as it was stuck(Hang) and as I restarted My laptop I opened a browser to resume my work and I noticed I was not able to connect to the internet after checking my internet connection I noticed that my browser was showing some DNS error so I googled and I got the solution.

Q1. Can anyone help me WHy such a problem occurred After my restart and the crash of protonvpn

After the solution, I quickly added nameservers to the /etc/resolve.conf file there were cases where many times I shut down my laptop while VPN was running but never such thing occurred.
And as I solved By editing the file it gets over written every time and it really irritates.
SO to summon Up

Can anyone tell help me why such a problem occurred
and second how to solve it as well as how to solve when the file gets overwritten.

Thank You.

Comment: VPNs work by using "routing" (`man ip ip-route`) to route all packets (encrypted) to the VPN on-ramp server. This setup was partially preserved across the reboot. Don't edit `/etc/resolv.conf`, it's managed by systemd. Start up and shutdown your VPN.

Comment: Thx Brother for the help  :) It worked.